# What is the meaning of putting class name inside the brackets?

Tags: android

While observing an existing  android application, I encountered this line of code:

```
((StoredVariables)this.getApplication()).getId
```

Why we are using this? What is the outcome of the code? Does it returns previously stored values from sharedPreference? No documentation found on internet to get an idea about it. Please explain.

Comment: StoredVariables might be your custom class, it is not android class

Comment: This must be a subclass of Application class into your project. Here you are trying to typecast this.getApplication to your subclass.

Comment: Nobody will tell you exactly what is `StoredVariables` since it is not an android class. you should edit your question and specify what is `this`, change question title to sth. like: "Explain unknown class name" not actual line of code, and place this line of code inside text. Then I can remove my downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably a little newbie in Java also

I'm not sure about what is "`this`" in `this.getApplication()` and what the `StoredVariable` is, since it is not an android class...

But here are recommendations for you:

1. Look for `StoredVariable` in your class in imports section. You can find something like `import my.project.StoredVariable;`
2. Open the class (I'm 80% sure it will be interface) to see the class (this is already answer to your question)
3. See `getId()` method there

To know more about usage of `StoredVariables`. If this line of code is placed inside class that extends some `Activity` (e.g. `AppCompatActivity`, `Activity` e.t.c.)

1. Open AndroidManifest.xml and look into `<application>` tag to find `android:name` in there. Open class with that name (ctrl + click or cmd + click on class name)
2. This class is extending `Application` class (or subclass) and implementing `StoredVariables` interface, or it is directly `StoredVariable` class